# DataTables warning: table id=appraisalTable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7 Laravel

Tags: laravel, datatables

Here is the code of the ajax data table this where I pass the data to the route. but it does not work. please give me any solution how can I do now. I am trying very much time.

```
   var table = $('#appraisalTable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: "{{ route('performance.appraisal.index') }}",
        columns: [
            {data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex'},
            {data: 'company_name', name: 'company_name'},
            {data: 'employee_name', name: 'employee_name'},
            {data: 'department_name', name: 'department_name'},
            {data: 'designation_name', name: 'designation_name'},
            {data: 'date', name: 'date'},
            {
                data: 'action',
                name: 'action',
                orderable: true,
                searchable: true
            },
        ],

        //----- Start Checkbox ----
        'columnDefs': [
            {
                "orderable": false,
                'targets': [0]
            },
            {
                'targets': 0,
                'checkboxes': {
                    'selectRow': true,
                    'selectAllRender': '<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"><label></label></div>'
                },
                'render': function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    if (type === 'display') {
                        data = '<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="dt-checkboxes"><label></label></div>';
                    }

                    return data;
                },
            }
        ],
```

Here is the controller code  where i pass data to view  I think there is problem but i can't find it

```
    public function index(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax())
    {
        $appraisals = Appraisal::with('company:id,company_name','employee:id,first_name,last_name','department:id,department_name','designation:id,designation_name')
                  ->get();

        return DataTables::of($appraisals)
            ->setRowId(function ($row)
            {
                return $row->id;
            })
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('company_name', function ($row)
            {
                return $row->company->company_name ?? '' ;
            })
            ->addColumn('employee_name', function ($row)
            {
                return $row->employee->first_name.' '.$row->employee->last_name;
            })
            ->addColumn('department_name', function ($row)
            {
                return $row->department->department_name ?? '';
            })
            ->addColumn('designation_name', function ($row)
            {
                return $row->designation->designation_name ?? '' ;
            })
            ->addColumn('date', function ($row)
            {
                return date("d M, Y", strtotime($row->date));
            })
            ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                $actionBtn = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" name="edit" data-id="'.$row->id.'" class="edit btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="dripicons-pencil"></i></a>
                            &nbsp;
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" name="delete" data-id="'.$row->id.'" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="dripicons-trash"></i></a>';
                return $actionBtn;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
    }

    $companies = company::select('id','company_name')->get();

    return view('performance.appraisal.index',compact('companies'));
}
```

I have tried many times but can't solve all code are okay. but when I reloaded this page it now works. and this page data now showing.

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve ??

Comment: I want to show my data on data table but its say warning

Comment: Did you look at the ["please see" web page](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7)? Did you follow the diagnosis steps it describes? What were the results?

Comment: The results  show  datatable warning   table id whic i given the title

Comment: Right - and did you follow the instructions?

Answer (score 1):

[This webpage explains what your error is and how to diagnose it](http://datatables.net/tn/7).

The problem with your code is that your ajax request is returning something other than a `200 OK` response.

Comment: Thanks there was a problem I find out it. thanks for respons